# How do unselect after the target has changed IE?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am working with a dynamic element list of checkboxes and I am at a lose as to how I can go about deselecting the elements after I've processed the request: http://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph0/k7uLg/15/

```
document.attachEvent('onclick', function (e) {

    var myBtn = document.getElementById('mybutton')
    var target = e.srcElement;

    if (target.name == "mycheckbox1" || target.name == "mycheckbox2") {
        if(target.checked){
            myBtn.disabled = false;
           // list.addRecord(target);
        } else if(!list.hasItems()) {
            myBtn.disabled = true;
            target.checked = false;
        } 
        if(list.hasItems()) {
            myBtn.disabled = false;
        }      
    } 
});

function someFunction() {
   alert("Some function");
}
```

Here's the Html:

```
<input type="button" id='mybutton' value="Click" disabled onclick="someFunction()"/>   
<input type="checkbox" name='mycheckbox1'  /> 
<input type="checkbox" name='mycheckbox2'  />
```

So, in summary after the button has 'do something' how would I then deselect the checked checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You could get all of the checkbox elements by type and then set them to false.

```
function unselect() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
  {
    if(elements[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox')
        elements[i].checked = false;
  }
}
```

It isn't very sexy but it gets the job done.

Comment: The problem with IE is that it doesn't allow to check 'type'.

Comment: What version of IE are you working with? I just tested my code on IE and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use

```
$("input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
```

this will uncheck all the checkboxes. I have also attached working copy of your code.

```
$(document).click(function (event) {

var myBtn = document.getElementById('mybutton');
var target = event.target;

if (target.name == "mycheckbox1" || target.name == "mycheckbox2") {
    if(target.checked){
        myBtn.disabled = false;
       // list.addRecord(target);
    } else if(!list.hasItems()) {
        myBtn.disabled = true;
        target.checked = false;
    } 
    $("input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
    if(list.hasItems()) {
        myBtn.disabled = false;
    }      
  } 
});
```

I hope this will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using Jquery?

Comment: if u don't want to use jquery.....Then u should go by the previous answer by @daniel....I have tested it in IE version 9.0.8 n it is working absolutely fine....but according to me u should use jquery version as jquery does things efficiently and u have no need to worry about the compatibility issues in the near future...this is just a suggestion....